# Webstorm on centos 6.5

Tags: java, html, webstorm

I've downloaded and extracted the tar file, but when I try to run the webstorm.sh file, I get the error:

```
"No JDK found. Please validate either WEBIDE_JDK, JDK_HOME or JAVA_HOME environment variable points to valid JDK installation.
```

I have Java installed:

```
[root@local.host]# java -version
java version "1.7.0_51"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.4.1.el6_5-x86_64 u51-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

[root@local.host]# ls -lah /etc/alternative/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 46 Jan 27 23:06 /etc/alternatives/java -> /usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java
```

I've also set the environment path, although I'm not 100% certain of it's correctness. Contents of .bash_profile:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If you check the [System Requirements and Installation](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/system-requirements-and-installation.html) page of WebStorm's website, you will see the following requirements for Linux...

> System Requirements
>
> - Intel Pentium III/800 MHz or higher (or compatible)
> - 512 MB RAM minimum, 1 GB RAM recommended
> - 1024x768 minimum screen resolution
> - Oracle (Sun) JDK 1.6 or higher. **Open JDK is not supported.**
> - GNOME or KDE desktop.

And as confirmed by your system...

```
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (rhel-2.4.4.1.el6_5-x86_64 u51-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

This is why your WebStorm is complaining about a `valid JDK installation`.

As cited in WebStorm's website, the article [Swapping OpenJDK for Sun JDK on Ubuntu](http://theaccidentalcoder.com/content/swapping-openjdk-sun-jdk-ubuntu) can be useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

The Sun JDK and OpenJDK are contained within the same installer. OpenJDK is used by default. After downloading and installing the JDK from the Oracle site, to specifically use Sun JDK, the following command must be run:

```
[root@local.host]# alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/java/latest/jre/bin/java 200000
```